# Include external .js in Cocoon / XSLT

Tags: javascript, xslt

I'm trying to include an external .js file in a page I'm building in Cocoon / XSLT.

Dir Struct:

```
/my_project
    /xsl/my_page.xsl
    /js/my_scripts.js
    sitemap.xmap
```

In Sitemap:

```
<map:match pattern="my_page.html">
    <map:generate src="cocoon:/my_data.xml" />
    <map:transform src="xsl/my_page.xsl" type="xslt2">
        <map:parameter name="baselink" value="{baselink:SitemapBaseLink}" />
    </map:transform>
    <map:serialize type="html5" />
</map:match>
```

In my_page.xsl:

```
<xsl:param name="baselink" />
...
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js">&#160;</script>
<script src="../js/my_scripts.js" type="text/javascript">&#160;</script>
```

In my_scripts.js, I have only one line for testing:

```
console.log('Success');
```

When I look at the source in the browser, I see that the script tag is included, but the log statement above doesn't execute.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        …
    </head>
    <body>
        …
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"> </script>
        <script src="../js/my_scripts.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So, although the script tag is in the code, I'm not sure it's actually pointing to the source - or the log statement would execute.

When I look at the JavaScript section of the Network tab (Firebug), I see:

```
GET my_scripts.js 200 OK
```

And the following entry is in the console:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> my_scripts.js (line 1)
```

Is there anything else / "special" I need to do in order to include an external .js in XSL?

Thanks!

Comment: Please include the HTML this generates. Also include the `<xsl:output>` directives that are in effect for your XSLT.

Comment: Added in post above.

Comment: While you're at it, when you look at the browser console in the network tab, do you see the JS file being fetched with a status of 200 (or 304) and the correct content type?

Comment: Okay, I actually left out an important line in the code above, on purpose for brevity. However, when I looked at the network tab, I saw that line of code had a problem in it. The line was an include for jQuery from a CDN. The problem was that I didn't have a space between the start/close script tags. I fixed that, and added the code/output above. Now, I see that the my_scripts.js file is being included, but I'm getting a new error in the console: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> on line #1 in the my_scripts.js file. Status code for my_script.js in 200.

Comment: I suppose a question rewrite is in order at this stage. Include the exact contents of the JS file and the exact error. Chances are this isn't an XSLT issue.

Comment: You're right. I've edited it (a lot stayed the same) to add more detail on what's in the Firebug console and network tab. The .js file only has the one console.log('Success'); line in it for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed.

Added the following to the Sitemap:

```
<map:match pattern="**.js">
    <map:read src="js/{1}.js" mime-type="text/javascript" />
</map:match>
```

Changed javascript include to :

```
<script src="my_scripts.js" type="text/javascript">&#160;</script>
```

Comment: Nice one! Solved yourself and shared the solution. (BTW remember [I asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094226/include-external-js-in-cocoon-xslt#comment42694421_27094226) whether the script was being served with the correct content type?)

Comment: Yup, you did. And, you were right. Thanks for helping out!